# Using WP_Query - how to display something IF there are no results

Tags: php, query

I've used WP_Query to query and display events.  In some cases, though, there are no events to be displayed and I'd like to display a friendly message when that happens instead of displaying nothing - but I'm not sure how to do this.  If it was a mysql query I know I could use if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) but I don't think that works with WP_Query.  Is there something else that will work?

Thanks very much for any help you can give me.
Sarah

Answer (score 9):

So, let's say `$query` is your WP_Query object. I.e.

```
    $query = new WP_Query($some_query_args );
```

Then you can set up 'the loop', by

```
    $query->get_posts();
```

Then to check if there are actually any returned results:

```
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
       //Use a While loop to show the results
    else:
       //No results, let's show a message instead. 
       //This is how WordPress' twentyeleven theme does it, but you can format it how you like:
        ?>

      <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
          <header class="entry-header"> 
              <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
          </header>

          <div class="entry-content">
             <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no events were found.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
         </div>
    </article>
    <?php
    endif;
```

Keep in mind the logic, must be inside php tags, while the HTML markup must be outside.

*Disclaimer: the syntax might not all be correct, I've not tested it. But check out index.php of the TwentyEleven to see what they do.*

Comment: Thank you!  That's definitely given me a push in the right direction.  What I have at the moment is: while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();, then the stuff inside the loop, then endwhile;.  Using your example above, what code would I use to set up the while loop instead?

Comment: That's correct - just insert the 'while' code inside in between the 'if' and the 'else' above in mine :D.